# Use Google script function as formula - Error Exception: You do not have permission to call setActiveSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to build a new formula using Google Script that loop through my rows to check if a value already exists, and then assign this value to a cell.

| Street | # | Nb units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Barclay | 3065 | 10 |
| Barclay | 3065 | #ERROR! |

This is my formula :

```
function check_address() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var pap = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Feuil1'), true)
  var lastRow = pap.getLastRow(); //get last row
  var nb_units = pap.getRange(lastRow, 3) //get the range where the value will go
  var currentStreet = pap.getRange (lastRow, 1).getValue(); //check the last street name
  var currentAddress = pap.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue() // check the last street number
  var data = pap.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(currentStreet == data[i][0]){ // if the last address exists
      units = data[i][2];
      break                          // then the number of units for this address = Nb units of row [x]
    }
    else{
    }
  };
  nb_units.setValue(units) // sets the range defined earlier
}
```

Problem I have is that when I use it as a formula I get this error : Exception: You do not have permission to call setActiveSheet (line 3).

Is there a way to modify the function so I can use it as a formula ?

Comment: You don't need the setActiveSheet() so don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use this as custom formula it's easier to feed the range arguments to the Apps Script function and check from there:

```
function CHECKADDRESS(datarange, current) {
  for (i = 0; i < datarange.length; i++) {
    if (current[0][0] === datarange[i][0] && current[0][1] === datarange[i][1]) {
      return datarange[i][2];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]